# Magento - Use stored procedure array result set as a collection

Tags: mysql, magento

I have written a mysql stored procedure in my magento database to perform a complex operation and want to use them in my magento code. I was able to call the procedure from my magento code and fetch the resultset in an array. Now i wanted to use this resultset as maybe a model to do further joins using joinattribute or to be more specific, i want to transfer this output resultset from the stored procedure into a collection so that i can use the getcollection methods. how do i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [thread on joining procedure results](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,272206,272339#msg-272339):

> > Is it possible to join a table on the results from a stored procedure within a single query?
>
> No.

So it looks like you'll have to do it the long way and use the array as a parameter.

```
// $collection is a collection
// $results is the stored procedure results as an array
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('ATTRIBUTE_NAME', array('in'=>$results));
```

<sub>For similar tricks with collections see "Other Comparison Operators" [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections).</sub>

Comment: Not the answer i am looking for ! my question was i have a stored procedure result in an array and can i use that array as a collection to implement pagination ?